# Where does CMake look for modules? (trying to fix errors after environment changes)

Tags: qt, ubuntu, cmake, environment-variables

I'm trying to build a QT5 application using CMake, and it builds fine under normal circumstances.

But I need to build it with the Linux AM335X toolchain / SDK, so I source the "environment-setup" script, which makes a large amount of changes to environment variables.

Now when I run CMake I get this error:

> CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:27 (find_package):
>
> By not providing "FindQt5Quick.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
> asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Quick",
> but CMake did not find one.
>
> Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Quick" with any
> of the following names:
>
> Qt5QuickConfig.cmake
>
> qt5quick-config.cmake
>
> Add the installation prefix of "Qt5Quick" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
> "Qt5Quick_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
> "Qt5Quick" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
> been installed.

This is my CMakeLists.txt file.

```
project(SPRITER_PLUS_PLUS_QT)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.9)
option(COMPILE_QML_PLUGIN "Compile the qml plugin" ON)

if(${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR} STREQUAL ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})
   message(FATAL_ERROR "In-tree build attempt detected, aborting. Set your build dir outside your source dir, delete CMakeCache.txt from source root and try again.")
endif()

set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib")
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib")
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin")
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake")

# Compiler options
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -fmax-errors=2 -Wall -Wno-unused-function")
set(CMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON)
set(SKIP_EXAMPLES ON)

include("QtCreatorResources")

#Qt
# Find includes in corresponding build directories
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
# Instruct CMake to run moc automatically when needed.
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)

find_package(Qt5Quick REQUIRED)    # this is the offending line.
find_package(Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Multimedia REQUIRED)

add_subdirectory(spriterplusplus EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)
add_subdirectory(qtdocumentwrapper EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)
add_subdirectory(qt)
add_subdirectory(example)

qtcreator_add_project_resources(${SPRITER_ENGINE_SRCS} ${SPRITER_ENGINE_HDRS})
qtcreator_add_project_resources(${SPRITER_EXAMPLE_SRCS} ${SPRITER_EXAMPLE_HDRS})
```

My main question is how do I tell where it's looking for `Qt5QuickConfig.cmake` which exists in several locations on my machine? I have checked `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` but it appears to be the same (just the location I'm running CMake from) whether I run successfully or within the toolkit environment.

Any other hints to fix this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Note: I've already done stuff like `sudo apt-get install qtdeclarative5-dev` which is why it works in the normal environment. I'm guessing in the SDK's environment, it no longer knows where that put it hence my question.

Comment: Run cmake with additional ``--debug-find`` option, and it will tell where `Qt5QuickConfig.cmake` is actually searched. As for `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` variable, it doesn't affect on searching this file. That variable affects on searching of `FindQt5Quick.cmake` file, as the error message tells you.

Comment: @Tsyvarev There doesn't appear to be a `--debug-find` option. I tried it and nothing in the output was different. I did `cmake --help` and there is no mention of the option.

Comment: So you CMake is older than 3.17, where given option was introduced: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.17/manual/cmake.1.html. If you know where your  `Qt5QuickConfig.cmake` is located, then you should be able to set `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` or `Qt5Quick_DIR` variables as the error message suggests.

Comment: I don't know if the way you search for qt works too; the way I use `find_package` to look for qt is `find_package(Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Core Widgets ... CONFIG)`; this would require you to add the qt installation directory to `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` on the first configuration (alternatively adjust the cache later)... This of course assumes the cmake configuration files are installed on your system.